# How can this datetime variable be converted to the string equivalent of this format in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, datetime-format

I am using python 2.7.10

I have a datetime variable which contains `2015-03-31 21:02:36.452000`. I want to convert this datetime variable into a string which looks like `31-Mar-2015 21:02:36`.

How can this be done in python 2.7?

Comment: A quick trip to [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/stdlib.html#dates-and-times) would have given you a hint to where to look in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use strptime to create a datetime object then use strftime to format it they way you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

s= "2015-05-31 21:02:36.452000"

print(datetime.strptime(s,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%m:%S"))
31-May-2015 21:05:36
```

The format string is the following:

```
%Y  Year with century as a decimal number.
%m  Month as a decimal number [01,12].    
%d  Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].
%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23]. 
%M  Minute as a decimal number [00,59].
%S  Second as a decimal number [00,61]. 
%f  Microsecond as a decimal number
```

In strftime we use %b which is:

```
%b  Locale’s abbreviated month name.
```

Obviously we just ignore the microseconds in the output string.

If you already have a datetime object just call strftime on the datetime object:

```
print(dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%m:%S"))
```